# TCL how to sort a nested dictionary by value

Tags: sorting, dictionary, tcl

Input is a dictionary called b

```
puts $b
h1 {tP 20} h2 {tP 30} h3 {tP 40} h4 {tP 50}
```

Objective - to sort this dict by tP values.

Function i have till now is

```
proc sortValue {dict args} {
    set l {}
    dict for {k v} $dict {
        lappend l [list $k $v]
    }
    return [concat {*}[lsort -real -decreasing -index 1 {*}$args $l]]
}
```

How do I modify this to step into the dict another level ?

**Expected output**

```
h4 {tP 50} h3 {tP 40} h2 {tP 30} h1 {tP 20}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Treat the dict as a list with an even number of elements (which it is)

```
lsort -integer -decreasing -stride 2 -index {end end} $b
```

```
h4 {tP 50} h3 {tP 40} h2 {tP 30} h1 {tP 20}
```

The first "end" is to access the last element of the stride, the second "end" is to access the last element of that index.

---

You can do this in 8.5

```
set temp [list]
set sorted [dict create]

dict for {key value} $b {
    lappend temp [list $key $value]
}
foreach pair [lsort -integer -decreasing -index {end end} $temp] {
    dict set sorted {*}$pair
}
```

---

just saw your edited comment: yes, of course it will change. Here's a bit of a Schwartzian transform:

```
% set b {h1 {tP 20 lp 1} h2 {tP 30 lp 2} h3 {tP 40 lp 3} h4 {tP 50 lp 4} }
h1 {tP 20 lp 1} h2 {tP 30 lp 2} h3 {tP 40 lp 3} h4 {tP 50 lp 4}
% set temp [list]
% dict for {key subdict} $b {lappend temp [list [dict get $subdict tP] $key $subdict]}
% set sorted [dict create]
% foreach tuple [lsort -int -decr -index 0 $temp] {dict set sorted {*}[lrange $tuple 1 end]}
% set sorted
h4 {tP 50 lp 4} h3 {tP 40 lp 3} h2 {tP 30 lp 2} h1 {tP 20 lp 1}
```

Comment: Thanks! Is this compatible in 8.5 too ?

Also, would the method change if my starting dict was h1 {tP 20 lp 1} h2 {tP 30 lp 2} h3 {tP 40 lp 3} h4 {tP 50 lp 4} , and I still wanted to sort by tp as you helped me do above.

Comment: Cool thanks. Read a bit on the lsort and found -index {end 1} would sort my given case by first index. Tested and found to be working. Cheers

Comment: Happy coding :)